# How to convert an arbitrary-dimension array of primitives into it's boxed counterpart

Tags: java, boxing

If I have an array such as

`int[][][] myArr = new int[][][] {{{1}, {1, 2, 3}}, {}};`

how can I convert it it's boxed counterpart, i.e.

`Integer[][][] myArrBoxed = ...`

Answer (score -1):

Usage of below code:

```
int[][][] myArr = new int[][][] {{{1}, {1, 2, 3}}, {}};
Integer[][][] myArrBoxed = (Integer[][][]) boxArray(myArr);
```

This code uses Apache Commons Lang for some convenience functions, specifially `ArrayUtils#toObject` and `ClassUtils#primitiveToWrapper`, and some newer java features. It can be pretty easily retrofit to not use them, although it would be even more verbose than it already is.

```
/**
 * Box an arbitrary-dimension primitive array
 * @param arr an arbitrary-dimension primitive array, e.g., an int[][][]
 * @return arr, but boxed, e.g., an Integer[][][]
 */
public static Object boxArray(Object arr) {
    return boxArray(arr, toWrapperArrayType(arr.getClass().getComponentType()));
}

private static Object boxArray(Object arr, Class<?> boxedType) {
    if (arr instanceof int[])
        return ArrayUtils.toObject((int[]) arr);
    if (arr instanceof long[])
        return ArrayUtils.toObject((long[]) arr);
    if (arr instanceof double[])
        return ArrayUtils.toObject((double[]) arr);
    if (arr instanceof float[])
        return ArrayUtils.toObject((float[]) arr);
    if (arr instanceof short[])
        return ArrayUtils.toObject((short[]) arr);
    if (arr instanceof byte[])
        return ArrayUtils.toObject((byte[]) arr);
    if (arr instanceof char[])
        return ArrayUtils.toObject((char[]) arr);
    if (arr instanceof boolean[])
        return ArrayUtils.toObject((boolean[]) arr);

    if (!(arr instanceof Object[] objectArr))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("arr is not an array");

    int length = Array.getLength(arr);
    Object[] newArr = (Object[]) Array.newInstance(boxedType, length);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        newArr[i] = boxArray(objectArr[i], boxedType.getComponentType());

    return newArr;
}

/**
 * Converts the type of an arbitrary dimension primitive array to it's wrapper type
 * i.e. `toWrapperArrayType(int[][][].class) == Integer[][][].class`
 */
private static Class<?> toWrapperArrayType(Class<?> primitiveArrayType) {
    int levels = 1;

    Class<?> component = primitiveArrayType.getComponentType();
    for (; component.isArray(); levels++)
        component = component.getComponentType();

    Class<?> boxedType = ClassUtils.primitiveToWrapper(component);
    for (int i = 0; i < levels; i++)
        boxedType = boxedType.arrayType();

    return boxedType;
}
```

Comment: What is `objectArr`? This code doesn't compile.

Comment: @Nexevis it's a java 16 instanceof expression. It won't compile on lower versions

Comment: You can replace it with ((Object[]) arr).

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/language/pattern-matching-instanceof-operator.html

Comment: I'll try it out in Java 16, though it seems directly replacing it with your suggestion causes other issues in Java 8.

Comment: @Nexevis Class#arrayType is a java 12 only library function. My answer is designed for the latest version of java, as noted you will have to retrofit it somewhat to make it work for java 8